Restricting branch creation based on Azure DevOps group permissions
I want to restrict certain Azure DevOps groups so that they can only create new branches based on specific branches, such as development, and not on others like the master branch (as a example). Is there a way to achieve this using branch policies or permissions settings in Azure DevOps?
I have thought about changing the contribute permission to deny, but I'm not sure if that will work correctly.
If anyone knows how to do this or has experience with this, that would be of great help!

HI @Somebody_Data_Science, Have you got a chance to check the information in the answer below? Hope it can help resolve your concern in this post. Thx.

We can restrict a group/team of users from creating new branches by setting the security policy to Create branch as Deny; but it is NOT based on certain branch naming pattern.

I can fully understand the requirement for such a functionality is fairly reasonable and will be helpful for the project administrators to manage the branches in the repos. Per the current limitation, you may create a feature request via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion . That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.

Thankyou for giving me the information that I needed!
